# Unable to use Keyboard library with Arduino UNO even after changing the firmware

Tags: arduino-uno, library, arduino-leonardo, sketch, core-libraries

So I'm trying to use my UNO as an HID device. I followed [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-arduino-uno-work-like-leonardo/) tutorial, flashed the firmware and got the UNO to be detected as an HID device.

However, I am still getting the error

> 'Keyboard' not found. Does your sketch include the line '#include '?

Here's the code -

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2014 NicoHood
 See the readme for credit to other people.

 Keyboard example
 Press a button to write some text to your pc.
 See official documentation for more infos
 */

// include HID library
#include <HID.h>

const int pinLed = 13;
const int pinButton = 8;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pinLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinButton, INPUT_PULLUP);

  // Starts Serial at baud 115200 otherwise HID wont work on Uno/Mega.
  // This is not needed for Leonado/(Pro)Micro but make sure to activate desired USB functions in HID.h
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Sends a clean report to the host. This is important because
  // the 16u2 of the Uno/Mega is not turned off while programming
  // so you want to start with a clean report to avoid strange bugs after reset.
  Keyboard.begin();
}


void loop() {
  if (!digitalRead(pinButton)) {
    digitalWrite(pinLed, HIGH);

    // Same use as the official library, pretty much self explaining
    Keyboard.println("This message was sent with my Arduino.");
    Serial.println("Serial port is still working and not glitching out");

    // simple debounce
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite(pinLed, LOW);
  }
}

/*
Definitions:

 KEY_LEFT_CTRL
 KEY_LEFT_SHIFT
 KEY_LEFT_ALT
 KEY_LEFT_GUI
 KEY_RIGHT_CTRL
 KEY_RIGHT_SHIFT
 KEY_RIGHT_ALT
 KEY_RIGHT_GUI

 KEY_UP_ARROW
 KEY_DOWN_ARROW
 KEY_LEFT_ARROW
 KEY_RIGHT_ARROW
 KEY_BACKSPACE
 KEY_TAB
 KEY_RETURN
 KEY_ESC
 KEY_INSERT
 KEY_DELETE
 KEY_PAGE_UP
 KEY_PAGE_DOWN
 KEY_HOME
 KEY_END
 KEY_CAPS_LOCK
 KEY_F1
 KEY_F2
 KEY_F3
 KEY_F4
 KEY_F5
 KEY_F6
 KEY_F7
 KEY_F8
 KEY_F9
 KEY_F10
 KEY_F11
 KEY_F12

 KEY_PRINT
 KEY_SCROLL_LOCK
 KEY_PAUSE
 */
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was that the added HID library was conflicting with the core Keyboard/Mouse library. I replaced the core library with the new one and it worked without any problems.

Well one problem actually, it would ask for a platform.h. To solve this download the Arduino v1.5.7 BETA zip and find the platform.h file in it and paste it in your current Arduino directory.

Answer (score 0):

If I open the rar library file, than I see a file called Keyboard.h. I'm sure you need to include Keyboard.h, than the class Keyboard is known and you can use it in your sketch.

Comment: I've tried doing that... It doesn't work. Still gives the same error